# Add three text file into three datagridview at once

Tags: vb.net, winforms, datagridview

I want to load three text files into three datagridviews at once after I have all selected it in my folder. I want it automatically load the three text files I highlighted together into the three datagridviews. I have created in my form using VB.NET.

```
Private Sub PictureBox1_Click_1(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles PictureBox1.Click
     If OpenFileDialog1.ShowDialog = System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK _
Then
          DataGridView1.Rows.Clear()
          For Each Line In My.Computer.FileSystem.ReadAllText(OpenFileDialog1.FileName).Split(Environment.NewLine)
              DataGridView3.Rows.Add(Split(Line, ControlChars.Tab))
              DataGridView2.Rows.Add(Split(Line, ControlChars.Tab))
              DataGridView1.Rows.Add(Split(Line, ControlChars.Tab))
          Next

     End If
End Sub
```

Comment: and what's the problem you're experiencing with the current code?

Comment: the problem is unable to select the three text file in my open file folder at once, it can only select one text file,

Comment: example, i have three text files saved in a folder, i want to select the three at once and load it into the three datagridviews that i have in my form, but with the code i have above, it can only select one file at a go even if i press shift to highlight it

Comment: Is `MultiSelect` property set to true? To select multiple elements, the user can hold down the CTRL key while clicking the elements to select.

Comment: am looking for the  multiselect i didn't see it in my button property

Comment: where can i get it

Comment: *"the problem is unable to select the three text file"*. And yet that's not mentioned anywhere in your question. Maybe you should consider actually telling us what the problem is that you want solved. We can't read your mind. Getting files selected in an `OpenFileDialog` has nothing at all to do with loading data into `DataGridViews`, so you successfully diverted our attention away from the actual problem to something comnpletely irrelevant.

Comment: The problem here is that you didn't read the relevant documentation. You are having trouble using an `OpenFileDialog` so the very first thing you should have done was read [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-au/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.openfiledialog?view=windowsdesktop-7.0) for that type. If you had done that then you'd have seen that it has a [`FileNames`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-au/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.filedialog.filenames?view=windowsdesktop-7.0#system-windows-forms-filedialog-filenames) property that is exactly what you need.

Comment: For the record, you could have simply clicked the type name in your code and pressed F1 to open that documentation directly. Context-sensitive Help has been a thing in Windows apps for decades. Even without that, you could still have used the VS Help menu. I suggest that you bookmark/favourite the API documentation home page in your browser too.

Answer (score 2):

You need to iterate over the array of files returned by the OpenFileDialog.

Also, it is better to split the code up into smaller units as it's easier to debug and maintain.

I put one button and three DataGridView controls on a form and used this code:

```
Imports System.IO

Public Class Form1

    Function GetDataFiles() As String()
        Using ofd As New OpenFileDialog() With {.InitialDirectory = "C:\Temp",
                                                .DefaultExt = ".csv",
                                                .Multiselect = True,
                                                .Title = "Select 3 files"}

            If ofd.ShowDialog = DialogResult.OK Then
                Return ofd.FileNames
            End If

        End Using

        Return Array.Empty(Of String)

    End Function

    Sub LoadData()
        Dim nFiles = 3

        Dim srcFiles = GetDataFiles().Take(nFiles)

        If srcFiles.Count <> nFiles Then
            ' Probably need to ask user to select nFiles files.
            Exit Sub
        End If

        'TODO: Maybe find a better way of getting the DGVs.
        Dim dgvs = {DataGridView1, DataGridView2, DataGridView3}

        For i = 0 To nFiles - 1
            'TODO: Possibly read the files first to get the number of columns.
            Dim nCols = 4
            Dim dt = New DataTable()
            For j = 1 To nCols
                dt.Columns.Add($"DT{i}-Col{j}")
            Next

            Dim data = File.ReadAllLines(srcFiles(i)).Where(Function(s) Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(s))

            For Each s In data
                dt.Rows.Add(s.Split(ControlChars.Tab))
            Next

            dgvs(i).DataSource = dt

        Next

    End Sub

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        LoadData()

    End Sub

End Class
```

To get:

[image: Example of datagridviews populated from text files]

If you have dropped an OpenFileDialog onto the form then you need to select it, press <kbd>F4</kbd> to get to its properties, and in the "Behaviors" section change the "Multiselect" property to "True".

Comment: the solution does not work for my project, i have to skip it for now, so that i can continue  with the next stage of the project

Comment: @AYANWALELUKMON It's only a collection of pieces of code—you can pick the parts that you need to fit your project. Which part isn't working for your project?

Comment: CAN anyone help me with autocad design using vb.net

Comment: @AYANWALELUKMON Please read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)